# Checkboxfor MVC no se muestra

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Mi pregunta es como puedo solucionar un caso con el manejo del `checkboxfor` para mi modelo de datos tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "La fecha  no puede estar vacía ")]
public DateTime FechaProcesoRegistro { get; set; }
public bool registraProceso { get; set; }
```

y en la vista esto:

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.registraProceso)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.registraProceso)
</p>
```

Pero en el explorador no me aparece el cuadro del checkbox, ¿a qué se puede deber esto?

Comment: prueba a poner un `required` a `registraProceso`, a ver si el problema es con la inicialización. Alternativamente puedes hacer `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.registraProceso, new { style="display:fixed"})`

Comment: no funciono sigue sin mostrar el cuadro den checkbox, pero lo raro es que cuando le doy clic al label cambia el estado a true. por hay revise algo y al parecer es algo con el JS. no se bien.

Comment: Hola @usernovell que te parece si agregas el HTML generado por la vista y tambien los CSS que tienes. El codigo que tienes debería mostrar el checkbox, vamo'  a depurar :D Saludos.

Comment: si usas el developer tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12 he inspeccionas el html, puedes ver que el check esta renderizado, valida que style tiene aplicado

Comment: que browser utilizas? estaría bueno que muestres el html que se genera.

Answer (score 0):

Quizas esto pueda ayudarte, manteniendo la definicion en el modelo, si no te muestra en el explorador prueba borrando la cache del explorador, o finalmente vuelve a renderizar la vista

```
<p>   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.registraProceso)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.registraProceso) </p>
```